# Lower bound on the spectral gap in finite size critical systems with locality

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, critical-phenomena

Local quantum systems tuned to criticality are gapless in the thermodynamic limit. The rate at which the ground state spectral gap approaches zero as the system size $L \rightarrow \infty$ carries important information about the nature of low energy states. For example, if the critical theory approaches a 1+1D conformal field theory, then the spectral gap scales as $1/L$. The same conclusion holds for Fermi liquids. In contrast, for a non-local system like the Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev model or a Hermitian random Hamiltonian, the spectral gap can be as small as $e^{-\# L}$.

Since many of the known critical points can be described by CFTs/Fermi liquid theory, one naive conjecture would be that in any local system, the spectral gap cannot go to zero faster than $1/L$. But this is actually false! See a review of counterexamples in https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1605716113 where spectral gaps upper bounded by $1/L^2$ were found for 1D spin chains. Interestingly in the same counterexamples, the spectral gap is also provably lower bounded by a large power law $1/L^c$ with $c \gg 1$.

So the question is: for a general local quantum system at criticality (one can throw in additional assumptions if needed), is there a rigorous lower bound on the rate at which the spectral gap approaches zero in the $L \rightarrow \infty$ limit? If so, what are some implications of such a lower bound?

Comment: Do you have a rigorous or particular definition for "criticality"? Do you mean any system whose spectrum goes to [0,infinity) in the thermodynamic limit? And are you concentrating on 1d?